# integrate $ x e^{-x^2}$ from ${-\infty} $ to ${+\infty}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I suppose this question is very simple, but I still don't get where I am wrong.

I try to proof that the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2} dx$$
is equal to zero.
I suppose that by substitution $$z=-x^2, dz=-2 x dx$$
we obtain:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}-\frac{1}{2} e^{z} dz$$
but why is this equal to zero and not to minus one a half?

Comment: aren't the limits $-\infty$ to $-\infty$, so the integral is zero? Also the function is odd, so ..

Comment: Where are you getting zero for the upper bound? Both bounds could be $-\infty$ and the integral becomes clear. I personally would solve the indefinite integral, put x back in, and check the bounds on that. Avoid some confusion with infinite bounds.

Comment: Yes, these limits are wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Since substituting $x\mapsto-x$ gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0x\,e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=-\int_0^\infty x\,e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x
$$
we have that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=0
$$
as long as
$$
\int_0^\infty x\,e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x
$$
converges (in fact, it equals $1/2$).

Answer (score 2):

First it would be from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(-\infty,-\infty)$. You have $"-(-\infty)^2=-\infty"$ and $"-(\infty)^2=-\infty"$ so the change of variable 
$$
z=-x^2
$$ is *not allowed*: it is not *a bijection* between these intervals. You would better seperate your initial interval : $(-\infty,\infty)=(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$ then make the change of variable on each part.

Comment: (+1) The bijection requirement is the key to the difficulty in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Compute for $b>0$

$\int_{0}^{b} x e^{-x^2} dx+\int_{-b}^{0} x e^{-x^2} dx$ and let $b \to \infty$